# How can union two tables with their own order?

Tags: postgresql

postgresql version info:

```
psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.11 (Debian 13.11-0+deb11u1)
```

Create table :

```
create table sample1(ticker text,pe float,grow float,peg float);
create table sample2(ticker text,pe float,grow float,peg float);
```

Insert data for test in table sample1:

```
insert into sample1 (ticker,pe,grow,peg) 
values 
('dxp',16.8,2.809,0.07),
('vhm',5.4,0.656,0.08);
```

Insert data for test in table sample2:

```
insert into sample2 (ticker,pe,grow,peg) 
values 
('vig',11.1,-0.425,-0.26),
('lhc',9.1,-0.209,-0.43);
```

Data in two tables:

```
select * from sample1;
 ticker |  pe  | grow  | peg  
--------+------+-------+------
 dxp    | 16.8 | 2.809 | 0.07
 vhm    |  5.4 | 0.656 | 0.08
(2 rows)

Time: 0.749 ms
select * from sample2;
 ticker |  pe  |  grow  |  peg  
--------+------+--------+-------
 vig    | 11.1 | -0.425 | -0.26
 lhc    |  9.1 | -0.209 | -0.43
(2 rows)
```

Union them into one:

```
select * from sample1 union select * from sample2;
 ticker |  pe  |  grow  |  peg  
--------+------+--------+-------
 vig    | 11.1 | -0.425 | -0.26
 dxp    | 16.8 |  2.809 |  0.07
 lhc    |  9.1 | -0.209 | -0.43
 vhm    |  5.4 |  0.656 |  0.08
(4 rows)
```

Can union them with order in their own tables such as below?

```
 ticker |  pe  |  grow  |  peg  
--------+------+--------+-------
 dxp    | 16.8 |  2.809 |  0.07
 vhm    |  5.4 |  0.656 |  0.08
 vig    | 11.1 | -0.425 | -0.26
 lhc    |  9.1 | -0.209 | -0.43
```

Comment: Use a column that specifies the 'order'. In your sample, what makes lhc come after vig for example?

Answer (score 2):

The order in your both tables is not deterministic,  However, if you prefer the data from table1 to appear first, you can include a static column in both `SELECT` statements to define the order.

```
select *
from (
  select *, 1 as rn
  from sample1 
  union 
  select *, 2
  from sample2
) as s
order by rn, pe desc
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/HZF1mYez)

Comment: I am not downvoting, but as you said too, the order in tables is not deterministic.

Comment: Also, OP's sample query is using UNION, not UNION ALL. This would somewhat is closer to UNION ALL by introducing a differing column value.

Comment: @CetinBasoz that is correct, this approach effectively causes the UNION behave similarly to UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is implement `union all`:

```
select * from sample1 union all select * from sample2;
```